# Posets (partially ordered sets) in equational logic

Tags: lo.logic, order-theory, posets, lattice-theory

I know about equational logic, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#As_algebraic_structure, and understood that lattices are expressed equationally, i.e., in terms of equational logic (with function symbols $\wedge, \vee$ and by introducing the order $p \le q \; :\Leftrightarrow \; p = p \wedge q$).

The question is, can posets be expressed equationally (by some function symbols and an order determined by them)?

Comment: The algebraic representation in the question works just the same for semilattices. One can generalize it further to arbitrary directed posets, which can be algebraically represented by *directoids* (groupoids satisfying the identities $xx=x$, $((xy)z)x=(xy)z$, $y(xy)=xy$; one can restrict attention to commutative ones if desired), however, this is not so nice, as several distinct directoids may correspond to the same poset.

Comment: You can also look for classes of posets that _can_ be so represented. This comprises, for instance, all posets $(A;\leq)$ such that there is a binary  operation $\cdot$ on $A$ with $a\cdot b = a$ iff $a\leq b$. For instance, in [this paper](http://msp.org/pjm/1971/39-3/pjm-v39-n3-p15-p.pdf) by Gerhard, it is shown that posemigroups are not residually small (lots of them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The category of models of an equational theory (i.e. a variety in the sense of universal algebra) is always a [regular category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category), but the category of posets is not regular.

Comment: It's nice. It also resolves the cases of preorders and topological spaces.